# Python lxml xpath - returns all tags instead of selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

It is my firtst post, so Hello World!

I am writing a small webscraper in Python3 using 'requests' and 'lxml'. I have already made one and this is second project for different website.

I have encountered strange results - xpath method returns all tags, instead of selected DIVs. What is worse, output is multiplied by the number of occurrences of "offer-detail" DIV.

Xpath count return correct number of DIVs, I have also made a page.content dump to file and manually checked and it is all correct. I have checked xpath on website using 'Xpath helper' addon for Chrome - [screenshot](https://postimg.org/image/4v21sdd09/)

Scraper output - `http://pastebin.com/1bEdzXdJ` (long and messy)

But in my firsts project nothing like this happens and it still returns correct output.

Scraped website address: `http://www.ibood.com/pl/pl/all-deals/`

I would really appreciate any help from move advanced users :)

Code:

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from lxml import html

ua = UserAgent()
header_data = {'User-Agent': ua.chrome}

website = 'http://www.ibood.com/pl/pl/all-deals/'

page = requests.get(website, headers=header_data)

document = html.fromstring(page.content)

# //div[@class="all-offers"]/div/div[@class="offer-wrap"]
# # /div[@class="offer-detail"]

deals = document.xpath('//div[@class="offer-detail"]')

count = document.xpath('count(//div[@class="offer-detail"])')

print('count: ' + str(count))

for deal in deals:
    print(deal.xpath('//text()'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(deal.xpath('.//text()'))
```

`//` means from root start get all the descendants

`.//` means from current context node('deal') get all the descendants

this will return all node:

```
count: 4.0
['\n                                                    ', 'Przenośny głośnik Bluetooth UE MEGABOOM', '\n                            ', '\n                                ', 'Cena katalogowa ', '1.319,95 zł', 'Tylko', 'Dzisiaj', '579,95 zł', '                                ', '\n    ', '\n        ', '\n                    ', 'Przewidywany czas wysyłki dla tego produktu  to 13.01.2017', '\n            ', '\n    29,95 zł Dostawa', '                            ', '\n                            ', '\n                                ', '\n                                    ', '\n                                ', '\n                                                            ', '\n                            ', '\n                                                        ', '\n                            ', '\n                                                                    ', 'Wyprzedane!', '\n                                                            ', '\n                            ', '56%', 'zniżka', '\n                                               ']
```

Better way:

```
for deal in deals:
    print(deal.xpath('normalize-space(string())'))
```

out:

```
count: 4.0
Przenośny głośnik Bluetooth UE MEGABOOM Cena katalogowa 1.319,95 złTylkoDzisiaj579,95 zł Przewidywany czas wysyłki dla tego produktu to 13.01.2017 29,95 zł Dostawa Wyprzedane! 56%zniżka
Ukośnica Metabo KGS 254 M Cena katalogowa 1.639,95 złTylkoDzisiaj1.024,95 zł Przewidywany czas wysyłki dla tego produktu to 17.01.2017 39,95 zł Dostawa 11:18:18 lub do wyprzedania zapasów! Kupuję! 38%zniżka
3 pary bokserek SuperDry Cena katalogowa 179,95 złTylkoDzisiaj114,95 zł Przewidywany czas wysyłki dla tego produktu to 17.01.2017 29,95 zł Dostawa 11:18:18 lub do wyprzedania zapasów! Kupuję! 36%zniżka
2 Ładowarki akumulatorów Philips MultiLife Cena katalogowa 124,95 złTylkoDzisiaj34,95 zł Przewidywany czas wysyłki dla tego produktu to 11.01.2017 29,95 zł Dostawa 11:18:18 lub do wyprzedania zapasów! Kupuję! 72%zniżka
```

The `normalize-space` function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space.

Comment: I haven't seen your answer before posting mine, but yours is broader.

Comment: And thank you for 'normalize-space' - now it looks way better

Answer (score 0):

After posting question I have found solution:

I should use ".//" instead of just "//".

[This answer helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787054/xpath-lookup-via-lxml-starting-from-root-rather-than-element?rq=1)